# Minimum 6 of any characters in ng_pattern?

Tags: regex

I tried to find this but without success, i found for php but its not working.So i need regular expression for password so i need any charaters with mimimum 6....Any help?

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "password", @class = "form-control", @required = "required",ng_pattern=@"(.*){6,11} })
```

I  tried this but its not working for me.This is for php that i found.

I also find this but i dont know even how to use that.Im using angular

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern: `(.*){6,11}` you have an extra asterisk, remove it:

```
^.{6,11}$
```

This will match from 6 to 11 any character.